# What is the algorithm under the function seqefsub?

Tags: traminer

I wonder what is the underliyng algorithm implemented in the function `seqefsub`. In the book chapter "Exploratory mining of life event histories", and I found this:

> Efficient algorithms for extracting frequent subsequences have been pro-
>   posed in the literature among which the prominent ones are those of Bettini
>   et  al.  (1996),  Srikant  and  Agrawal  (1996),  Mannila  et  al.  (1997)  and  Zaki
>   (2001).   The  algorithm  implemented  in
>   TraMineR
>   is  an  adaptation  of  the
>   prefix-tree-based search described in Masseglia (2002).

However, the last reference is a PhD thesis in French. Is there any reference (in English) about this algorithm?

Thanks!

Victor

Comment: I would suggest to ask the author Florent Masseglia.

Comment: I will, thank you!